# Why is calling the ttk.Radiobutton.__init__() returning none?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter

```
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter

class Window(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.depth_options = Depth_options(self)
        
class Depth_options(ttk.Radiobutton):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.depth_var = tkinter.StringVar()
        button48 = super().__init__(master, value='48 mm', text='48 mm', variable=self.depth_var)
        button38 = super().__init__(master, value='38 mm', text='38 mm', variable=self.depth_var)
        button38.grid(row=1, column=1)
        button48.grid(row=0, column=0)


root = ThemedTk()
window = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This gives me the error

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid'

I tried doing this without classes and it worked without the error so the problem is probably in the use of OOPs, but I can't find it.(Any correction or advice regarding the use of classes is welcome)

Comment: `__init__()` is a constructor function of a class which is not used for creating instance of the class.

Comment: Your code appears to be trying to create two buttons inside a single button. Is that really what you're wanting to do? Or are you trying to create a group of two radiobuttons? If so, `Depth_options` should inherit from `Frame`, not `ttk.Radiobutton`.

Comment: But when I used the super().__init__() for Frame, it worked as if it was creating an instance of the Frame class.

Comment: But you didn't assign to a variable for Frame.